# Override magento 3rd party module

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, custom

I know that by making your own folder in **code/local**, you can override the Magento 1.9 core model. But if I want to override an 3rd party extension I've installed, what should I do? I don't want to change the code of an extension / module directly in it's folder, since it will cause the problem if there's update version later.

Comment: refer http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: If your 3rd party extension is in "community" pool, then you can override the extension in local pool same as other override method using local.

Comment: what if the 3rd party extension is already in local folder?

Comment: provide your 3rd party extension config.xml and model class that you want to rewrite